# String address to location on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map view in my android app, i'm just wondering if it's possible to have a function which takes in a String which would contain an address that would be passed onto google maps and returned as a geopoint location on the map?

If anyone knows where any tutorials are on how to do this, can you please point me to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Geocoder class, which you can pass an address string and it will return a list of actual addresses for the specified string.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Take a look at getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)